# ES6 module import fail

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

Now my project structure is like this:

project tree are like this:

```
project
|- index.html
|- a.js
|- b.js
|- c.js
```

in `index.html`, I use google map so it looks like this:

```
<script src="a.js" type="module">
</script>
<script src="b.js" type="module">
</script>
<script defer sync src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&libraries=drawing&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

So the input function of the whole project is the the callback function 
 `initMap`, it should be global and it is in the `a.js`:

```
import {x, z} from './b.js';
import y from './c.js';
window.initMap = () => {
   //
};
```

in `b.js`:

```
export function x() {
}
export function z() {
}
```

in `c.js`:

```
export default class c {
}
```

But the chrome suggests failed: `Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module does not provide an export named 'default'`.

And it suggests in the first `import` line of every js file `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: You have to use `import { x } from './b.js';` since your export x isn't a default x. Every non-default export has to be destructured.

Comment: Your edit seems to have removed the part that would have caused the error.

Comment: Yes I do use `{}` when importing non-default export, and I also import default export. Both wrong.